# creating rostopic

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am confused in how to create ROSTOPICs. In case of ROSMSG,one has to create a msg folder and then .msg file .Does one has to do the similar process for creating ROSTOPIC ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240905/creating-rostopic/) by [SaurabhR](https://answers.ros.org/users/27662/saurabhr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A topic is "created" (and will show up when using ROS introspection tools such as `rostopic`) as soon as a publisher or subscriber to that topic is created within a ROS node. From the [Python](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) and [C++](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)  creating a publisher/subscriber tutorials:

C++:

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);
```

Python:

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SaurabhR](https://answers.ros.org/users/27662/saurabhr/) on 2016-08-02**:
What is "chatter " here? Is it the name of topic?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-02**:
Yes. "chatter" is the name of the topic.